# Angular element in angular app

Tags: angular

I've created an angular element that I'd like to use in an other angular app. How can I do that?
I've tried to insert the script into the index.html but is says TypeError: parentJsonpFunction is not a function.
I'd like to import it somehow into a submodule where it will be used.

Comment: would you mind sharing your code on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you? also go through how to create [mcve]

Comment: I've similar to this : https://github.com/seeschweiler/angular-elements. I can use it in a static html page. The question is how can I insert/use this in other angular app just like a component can be used?

Comment: The reason why we want to see the code is to find errors in your implementation. Without it we can just point you to docs.

Comment: I don't have code because I don't know how can I insert custom element into angular app. Into static html I have to: <body>
  <pm-dashboard></pm-dashboard>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="promon-dashboard.js"></script>
</body>
where pm-dashboard is the element, but I can't do this in angular app index.html or template.